# Simulate a Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

I'm doing a custom CMD and trying to do an "exec" function to execute lot of command in a script file, but the problem is that basically it's triggered by a ReadLine so i would do an exec to directly execute the command like if that was a ReadLine.

Current code:

```
 string[] command = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
 switch(command[0])
 {
 // Example
 case "createdir":
     if(command.Length > 0)
     {
try
{
       Directory.Create(command.ToString().Replace("createdir ", string.Empty);
}
               // Catch all exceptions.
               catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("$error->" + ioe.ToString());
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("$error->" + uae.ToString());
                }
                catch(ArgumentNullException ane)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("$error->" + ane.ToString());
                }
     }
     else
     {
     try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory_loc);
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory created!");
                }
                // Catch all exceptions
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("$error->" + ioe.ToString());
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("$error->" + uae.ToString());
                }
                catch(ArgumentNullException ane)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("$error->" + ane.ToString());
                }
     }
 }
```

Edit: 
I'm doing a command-line console application which can create directory, create script files, execute script files, get computer / network informations and got a problem on execute command, commands are triggered by a string[] which is created at the `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: I'm confused.  When you say a "custom CMD", do you mean that you are writing a console application?   Also... where is your "script file" ? Please give a little more details.  Step by step, what do you want the user to do, and exactly what results you want to happen.

Comment: btw... move `if(command.Length > 0)` to above the `switch`.  It will never be zero where it is now

Comment: also... consider catching `catch (System.Exception ex)` instead of each individual exception.  That will catch all exceptions that are derived from the System Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do, but I do know that Console.ReadLine returns a string. With that knowledge you could just pass in the string that you would normally have associated with a readline. For Example

```
public void Main(){
  DoCommand("My executing string");
}

public void DoCommand(string commandLine){
 string[] command = commandLine.split('');
 switch(command){
   // Command List
 }
}
```

Comment: and I am curious as to what your case on the command would be.. being that you would be writing for umteen number of cases.. this is a poor example of an answer based on such an unclear question

Comment: I assumed that his "switch(command)" worked however it was supposed to. As that was given code and his question seems to be about how to "trigger" a Console.ReadLine()